# Adding automatically rows of an array

Tags: java, indexing

I have got a vector`[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]`and a correspondent 19xn matrix. I want to perform add operation in rows of the matrix based on the indexes of the vector. So I want to add the rows with correspondent index one, two, three and finally to construct a new array of 3 rows. How is it possible to  do so automatically, without knowing the prior index number(but knowning that they are sorted as it is in my example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options. Depending on whether performance or memory consumption are more important, and depending on how large the vector/matrix are in the actual use-case, and how the distribution of indices actually is. But a rather simple (IMHO elegant) and versatile solution might be to create a map that maps each index to the sum of matrix rows that has been computed so far. There might be solutions that are slightly more efficient or require less memory, but they will probably not be so readable.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AddMatrixRows
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double vector[] = {
            1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 
            2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 
            2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 
            3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0};
        double matrix[][] = new double[vector.length][];
        for (int r=0; r<vector.length; r++)
        {
            matrix[r] = new double[] { 12, 34, 56 };
        }

        double sums[][] = computeSums(vector, matrix);
        for (int r=0; r<sums.length; r++)
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sums[r]));
        }
    }

    private static double[][] computeSums(double vector[], double matrix[][])
    {
        Map<Integer, double[]> sumsByIndex = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, double[]>();
        for (int r=0; r<vector.length; r++)
        {
            int index = (int)vector[r];
            double array[] = sumsByIndex.get(index);
            if (array == null)
            {
                int numColumns = matrix[index].length;
                array = new double[numColumns];
                sumsByIndex.put(index, array);
            }
            add(array, matrix[index]);
        }
        return toArray(sumsByIndex.values());
    }

    private static double[][] toArray(Collection<double[]> collection)
    {
        double result[][] = new double[collection.size()][];
        int i = 0;
        for (double sum[] : collection)
        {
            result[i] = sum;
            i++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void add(double array[], double addend[])
    {
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            array[i] += addend[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the maximum number from the index array and create an output array with that size. Now you can loop through the other matrix and using the index vector, add it to the output array.